# Azure App service prefix missing when API end point is called through Swagger or Hangfire. API hosted in app service exposed through API gateway

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, swagger-ui, azure-api-management, hangfire

The base URL of my azure app service is "https://appname.domain.com". On opening the URL "https://appname.domain.com/pipelineAPI/swagger/index.html" my swagger index.html page loads successfully.
But when I'm trying to hit one of the API end point let's say "/api/Lookup/opportunityStatusTypes", the request URL does not contain the App Service name "**pipelineAPI**" and generate the URL "https://appname.domain.com/api/Lookup/opportunityStatusTypes".
Instead the URL should be "https://appname.domain.com/**pipelineAPI**/api/Lookup/opportunityStatusTypes" instead.
Here's my configuration in Program.cs file for swagger:

```
if (env.ApplicationName != Environments.Production)
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
#if DEBUG
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Pipeline API V1");
#else
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/pipelineApi/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Pipeline API V1");
#endif
    });
}
```

PS: I'm using Swasbuckle.AspNetCore version: 6.4.0

I went through this post and tried the changes as asked but I'm still seeing the same issue: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1338